# Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Consumer Group and Checkpoint Configurations

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

When considering how to horizontally scale Spring Cloud Stream microservices that consume Kinesis messages, I referenced [the Kinesis Binder documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#consumer-groups). We want to utilize Consumer Groups to ensure high availability and throughput for message processing, and we are currently utilizing the manual checkpointMode. We utilize manual checkpointing so that, if an exception occurs while processing the message, we control whether the message gets checkpointed or not. If an exception occurs, we retry processing the message via Spring Retry, and after a set number of retries, we shutdown/restart the microservice. At this point, since we didn't checkpoint on the failed message, Kinesis redelivers this message and we can continue to try processing it. We'd expect this to only occur when there are unexpected issues (e.g., we release buggy code, there is an error that occurs with an AWS service, etc.). We utilize this approach because it's critical that we process every single Kinesis message and don't just skip over failed messages if batch checkpointing were to be used.

My concern is that if multiple microservices are running in a competing consumer relationship by using consumer groups, and each microservice is doing manual checkpointing, how well will this scale? In other words, is there a performance hit we take by setting our checkpointMode to manual versus batch? If so, how could we utilize batch checkpointing yet still be able to ensure that any messages that experienced exceptions during processing get redelivered?

One last question I have is how does Kinesis deliver messages to our microservices if we utilize manual checkpointing? Does it still deliver a batch of records, or does it only deliver a single message at a time?